# Why is tomcat refreshing pages permanently

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, web.xml, server.xml

I am developing a spring mvc application on tomcat. the problem is that tomcat is refreshing pages each 2/3minutes, i can't see why !
my config is

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>messages</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
    <param-value>fr</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:portal.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>portal</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            <!--
                desactivation du context : utilisation du context parent
            -->
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>portal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>portal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>portal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ajax</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
        <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

server.xml

```
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
    -->
    <!--
   <Context docBase="/home/badrux/Work/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/portal" path="/" reloadable="true"></Context>
    -->
   <Context path="/images" docBase="/root/collecte/images" reloadable="false"/>
   <Context path="/statics" docBase="/root/collecte/statics" reloadable="false"/>
   <Context path="/sitemap" docBase="/root/collecte/sitemap" reloadable="false"/>
  </Host>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean be refreshing?

Comment: u can visite http://www.cercleimmobilier.ma/ , every 4 minute pages are refreshing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server cannot refresh page by itself, **there is no simple way of achieving that**. If you really experiencing such behavior, then somewhere in your code you have an explicit refresh (redirect perhaps? JavaScript maybe?) or AJAX is forcing page reload.

Please note that I said "simple way". You could do that by more sophisticated technologies, but it is highly unlikely that you are doing that.

Comment: i will check all my scripts !

Comment: I disabled all page scripts, but still have refreshing behavior, I think this a tomcat config problem. If u want I can attach my jsp+layout pages code

Comment: That could help, please do so.

Comment: I don't understand ur response?

Comment: I meant, that posting here your JSP and JavaScript can help us with solving this puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

You have a:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="240" />
```

in the page header, which means you are telling the browser to refresh the page every 4 minutes (240 seconds).

As an additional observation, you're also creating a session when rendering the home page, which is probably an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: u are right, thanks Luke, the problem was <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="240" />. What do you mean by "you're also creating a session when rendering the home page" ?

Comment: @MokhlisseBadre, please reward Luke with accepting his answer :)

Comment: @Mokhlisse I mean there is a session created on the server when you browse to the main page - I can see the JSESSIONID being set. If there is no good reason for this then you should avoid the waste of server-side resources. Note that unless you use `<%@ page session="false" %>` in a JSP it will create a session if one doesn't already exist.